# Configure node-purge-ttl (delete expired nodes) on Puppet Enterprise (OpsWorks managed)

Tags: puppet, aws-opsworks, puppet-enterprise

I have an AWS OpsWorks Puppet Enterprise instance and I want to configure the node-purge-ttl property (https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.1/configure.html#node-purge-ttl).

After 3 days the disconnected nodes are purged and I want to avoid it, I need these nodes present on the Puppet Enterprise UI even if the last connection was 10 years ago (it's a business requirement)

I've tried to configure the node-purge-ttl by setting the value on PE PuppetDB Classification: (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxa46.png)

```
Class: puppet_enterprise::profile::puppetdb - node_purge_ttl=0s
```

(set to 0s, auto-deletion of nodes is disabled)

And setting these values on Data section:

```
puppet_enterprise::params - puppetdb_node_purge_ttl = 0s
puppet_enterprise::puppetdb - node_purge_ttl = 0s
```

but it doesn't work, after 3 days the nodes are purged

How can I configure it?

Thanks!